# Search the input text

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel Vba and I have written a program which searches the Input text and if it is present anywhere from Column A through Column L it should write the user input in Column V of that particular row. I am running into a error here on the `Do While Cells(i,1)<>""` line. Any advice in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub testing()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range, sAddress As Range
Dim store As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String, Device As String,  FailureUnitValue As String
Dim Occurence1ms As Integer, Occurence10ms As Integer, Occurence As Integer
Dim DeviceCellAdd As Variant, DeviceCellValue As Variant, FailureUnitAddress As Variant, Failure As Variant

Dim errorcode As Variant
Dim rowNum As Double
Dim i As Long


Dim lastrow As Double


errorcode = InputBox("Enter Error Code")

Worksheets("DUT1").Activate
Range("V:V").ClearContents


Set oRange = Range("G:G")

Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""

If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, errorcode, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

rowNum = ActiveCell.Row

Range("V:" & rowNum).Value = errorcode

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select


End If

i = i + 1


Loop



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is it flagging the error?

Comment: Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""

Comment: If you want u can change it conpletely . I should just get worked

Comment: You haven't set a value for `i`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set `i` equal to a valid column row number.

It's currently trying to evaluate `Do While Cells(0, 1) <> ""` which obviously doesn't make sense.

Put `i = 1` (or whatever row you wish to start at) on the line above.

Comment: I wrote i=1 now but now its showing errors in this line                                  If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, errorcode, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

Comment: i dont know if its a correct way to check a check the input text

Answer (score 0):

This is the description of your goal for the macro from your original question:

> "searches the Input text and if it is present anywhere from Column A
>   through Column L it should write the user input in Column V of that
>   particular row"

This code will accomplish that goal, commented to help provide clarity:

```
Sub tgr()

    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet         'Used to store the worksheet that contains the data
    Dim rngData As Range        'Used to store the range that contains the data
    Dim rngFound As Range       'Used to find all matches (if any)
    Dim rngOutput As Range      'Used to store cells where the output will be displayed (in column V)
    Dim strErrorCode As String  'Used to store the user input
    Dim strFirst As String      'Used to store the first found cell to prevent infinite loop

    'Get input from user
    strErrorCode = InputBox("Enter Error Code")
    If Len(strErrorCode) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DUT1")  'Set the ws variable to the worksheet that contains the data
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A:L")           'Set the rngData variable to the range that contains the data
    ws.Columns("V").ClearContents           'Clear column V of previous results

    'Check columns A:L for the provided input, checking for partial matches
    Set rngFound = rngData.Find(strErrorCode, rngData.Cells(rngData.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)

    'Was anything found?
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        'Nothing found, return error
        MsgBox "No matches found for [" & strErrorCode & "]"
    Else
        'Found a match, record first found cell and begin building the output range
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Set rngOutput = ws.Cells(rngFound.Row, "V")

        'Initiate a loop to find all matches
        Do
            'Build output range from matching cells using the Union method
            Set rngOutput = Union(rngOutput, ws.Cells(rngFound.Row, "V"))

            Set rngFound = rngData.FindNext(rngFound)   'Go to next matching cell
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst 'End loop when back to first found cell

        'Output the data to the output range
        rngOutput.Value = strErrorCode
    End If

End Sub
```